# Thicker margin line

Tags: tikz-pgf, line, frame

tell me please how to make these lines (frame) more thicker?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw ([line width=2.5mm, xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1cm]current page.south east);
Text
\vfill
Text
\vfill
Text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an option to affect a path (such as the line width), it should be placed after a `\path`, `\draw`, `\fill` or `\filldraw` macro directly. On the other hand, if the option is meant to affect (the position of) a coordinate, it should be placed inside this coordinate (before the x-value). But only very few options, mainly used for transformation, can be applied to coordinates directly.

I suggest that you have a look at the [PGF/Ti*k*Z manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) regarding which options can be used where.

Following this logic, the option `line width=2.5mm` should be placed directly behind the `\draw` macro, not inside the coordinate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[line width=2.5mm] ([xshift=1cm, yshift=-1cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-1cm, yshift=1cm]current page.south east);
Text
\vfill
Text
\vfill
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, thank you very much!